# disk util is very high + what the proactive steps we can do in order to minimize it

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux, cpu-usage, vmdk

Our Kafka cluster includes 12 VM RHEL 7.6 machines.

machine spec details:

1. CPU(s):14
2. Kafka disk is VMDK disk.  ( sdb disk)
3. RAM 48G

When Kafka cluster is working hard (when injection data to Kafka disk/s and intensive reading from disk) then we can see from `sar` report that VMDK disks utilization is very high almost 100%
And CPU iowait also reached around ~ 40%

when no writing/read to Kafka disk ( sdb ) , then disk utilization is around 1-3% and that's fine

here is example from the first Kafka machine, this example is similar to other machines across cluster

```
sar -p -d 5 15 | grep sdb

                  DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
11:45:44 AM       sdb    667.60  50776.00 114753.80    247.95    145.06    210.63      1.50    100.00
11:45:49 AM       sdb    484.60  40296.00 142994.40    378.23    145.80    343.71      2.06    100.00
11:45:54 AM       sdb    355.40  12758.40 170463.40    515.54    285.86    724.10      2.81    100.00
11:45:59 AM       sdb    477.40  26828.80 142663.20    355.03    219.43    419.59      2.10    100.02
11:46:04 AM       sdb    526.40  30964.80 116515.60    280.17    219.52    495.00      1.90     99.98
11:46:09 AM       sdb    387.20  26939.20 142214.60    436.86    192.80    405.45      2.58    100.00
11:46:14 AM       sdb    403.00  18192.00 130434.80    368.80    286.71    681.59      2.48    100.00
11:46:19 AM       sdb    608.00  50153.60  96733.40    241.59    163.63    336.13      1.65    100.04
11:46:24 AM       sdb    188.40   8406.40  87474.80    508.92    196.47    657.40      5.31     99.98
11:46:29 AM       sdb    749.40  54948.80 167797.40    297.23    207.97    388.29      1.33    100.02
11:46:34 AM       sdb    419.20  57480.00 110545.60    400.82    143.63    305.59      2.39    100.00
11:46:39 AM       sdb    549.60  34772.80 149058.60    334.48    144.77    286.05      1.82     99.98
11:46:44 AM       sdb    468.26  40547.70 130706.99    365.72    146.39    318.22      2.13     99.90
11:46:49 AM       sdb    412.40  21929.60 186562.40    505.56    144.34    363.23      2.42     99.98
11:46:54 AM       sdb    574.60  36830.40 177053.60    372.23    149.73    245.82      1.74    100.00
Average:          sdb    484.76  34122.49 137730.57    354.51    186.13    385.28      2.06     99.99
```

And from CPU report perspective

```
sar  5 15

12:12:45 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:12:50 PM     all      8.21      0.00      9.87     10.26      0.00     71.67
12:12:55 PM     all      6.50      0.00      7.65      7.78      0.00     78.07
12:13:00 PM     all      7.90      0.00      9.40     10.53      0.00     72.16
12:13:05 PM     all     11.83      0.00     13.24     26.62      0.00     48.31
12:13:10 PM     all     11.66      0.00     12.84     19.00      0.00     56.50
12:13:15 PM     all      8.23      0.00      9.98      9.52      0.00     72.26
12:13:20 PM     all      7.74      0.00      8.87     10.95      0.00     72.44
12:13:25 PM     all      6.70      0.00      7.92      9.10      0.00     76.27
12:13:30 PM     all      7.15      0.00      8.32      8.05      0.00     76.49
12:13:35 PM     all     12.84      0.00     14.12     15.17      0.00     57.87
12:13:40 PM     all      7.91      0.00      9.04     35.44      0.00     47.62
12:13:45 PM     all      9.20      0.00     10.63     11.09      0.00     69.09
12:13:50 PM     all      9.57      0.00     10.98      8.15      0.00     71.30
12:13:55 PM     all     10.85      0.00     12.61      7.39      0.00     69.15
12:14:00 PM     all     10.88      0.00     12.44      9.54      0.00     67.15
Average:        all      9.14      0.00     10.52     13.23      0.00     67.11
```

from RAM memory point of view I do not see a problem but not sure what is the bottleneck here and why disk util is very high

one direction is to increase the CPU from 14 core to 48 core, but maybe the fact that we get high values of CPU %IOWAIT , are as results of high disk utilization.

traffic that comes from producers are sending into a cluster is persisted to disk.
Therefore, the underlying throughput of the storage volume can become the bottleneck of the cluster.

In this case, it makes sense to add others kafka machines to the cluster.
or maybe add few additional disks to each Kafka machines ( as JBOD disks) in order to balance the intensive writing/reading.

appreciate to get any suggestion that can improve Kafka disk utilization

**Vmware disk details** (from vSphere client from edit settings)

```
SATA controller 0     AHCI
VM storage policy     VxRail RAID5 Default 
Sharing               No SHaring
Disk File             VxRail-VSAN_Datastore 
Disk mode             Dependent 
Virtual Device Node   SCSI controller 0
```

the results from vmstat when cluster is loaded

```
vmstat 1 20
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
18 13   1024 379388      0 54566428    0    0  1888  5137    0    0  4  4 47 45  0
 0 19   1024 328408      0 54606020    0    0     0  6853 11700 7288  2  2 12 85  0
 0 15   1024 330204      0 54618088    0    0 12004 56708 16881 8254  3  3 16 78  0
 0 13   1024 345284      0 54601404    0    0  3492 104672 5135 3067  0  1 43 56  0
 0 17   1024 324864      0 54620400    0    0   248 66547 16615 8477  2  4 31 63  0
 0 18   1024 367468      0 54577640    0    0     0 84404 13020 6995  2  3  6 90  0
 0 21   1024 327480      0 54611036    0    0  8536 125999 29355 37872  4  7 18 71  0
 0 19   1024 362180      0 54581692    0    0  7692 66464 4167 2717  0  0 33 66  0
 0 19   1024 419264      0 54523248    0    0     0 46409 1799 1825  0  0 27 73  0
 0 14   1024 356708      0 54586004    0    0     4 78656 17169 9841  3  4 23 70  0
 0 14   1024 407352      0 54539976    0    0     0 136732 4554 4673  0  1 20 79  0
 0 12   1024 389672      0 54557752    0    0  5832 59124 9619 5537  1  2 25 71  0
 0 14   1024 431880      0 54513164    0    0   948 94160 14272 7229  2  3 30 65  0
 0 15   1024 440300      0 54502784    0    0  9140 136328 10626 5296  1  1 38 60  0
 0 13   1024 441708      0 54501948    0    0  7652 62132 4663 2756  0  1 33 66  0
 0 14   1024 449396      0 54492664    0    0   416 64790 1955 1757  0  0 33 66  0
 0 17   1024 424028      0 54520452    0    0   484 114372 16674 7946  2  3 25 70  0
 0 18   1024 441912      0 54499924    0    0     0 82027 2752 2100  0  0 22 78  0
 0 14   1024 473604      0 54468560    0    0     0 60188 2021 2212  0  0 22 78  0
 1 14   1024 420224      0 54525684    0    0  8576 128225 21739 9684  9  4 27 60  0
```

Comment: Let me ask again: what is the result of command `vmstat 1 3`?

Comment: not all the time disks util are with 100% now cluster not works too hard and util is low , once util became 100% then I will send

Comment: Please add the result when the system is not loaded and when is loaded. This may reveal some points

Comment: I update the post with vmstat results

Comment: Are you using hard drives?  Obviously SSD or M.2 would be much faster if you were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in `vmstat` (when the machine is loaded) you have serious amount of I/O operations, you have big amount of interrupts (usually for again I/O operations) and you have significant percantage ot process time in waiting state (which is usually wait for resources, with high probability I/O ops).

So my opinion is you should add disks and make Kafka to spread the load over all the disks. As you are in virtualized environment you should add disks from different datastores.  Will be much better if the datastores have own HDDs (not shared), even better if these HDDs of datastore use different (SATA/SAS) controllers (or FC/Ethernet interfaces if you use SAN/NAS) than currently used datastore.

In short - add more storage, accessible via different communication channels.

You can try to change in `/etc/sysctl.conf` some parameters to tune the system for Kafka:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
vm.dirty_ratio=80
vm.max_map_count=1200000
```

Because I see some swap space used (in `vmstat`) will be wise also to add:

```
vm.swappiness=1
```

Comment: first thank you for your post answer, about what you said. "add disks and make Kafka to spread the load over all the disks"  .  you means to add for example 3-5 disks on each kafka machine ? so we have for example kafka disks as sdc,sdd,sde,sdf,sdg  etc?   ( this situation is actually Kafka with JBOD disks )

Comment: Based on my humble knowledge about Kafka - yes, you should add disks and as far as I remember channels in Kafka (or something like) to make Kafka buffer the incoming messages in parallel more efficiently. There was something about configure channels to cache in different directories (and these directories are located in different disks)

Comment: About vmstat output and "serious amount of I/O" , what is the related column that you are looking that show the serious amount of I/O values ?

Comment: 9 and 10, `bi`, `bo`. For me `bo` is much more than I will consider normal

Comment: thank you, now its clear, do you think we can do some tune with kernel parameters in order to improve the performance about the disks?

Comment: I do not think you can do much because (having in mind Kafka way of operating) You have a lot of I/O operations ( read from input streams, store in temporary cache, send to channel, eventually do some changes, store it somewhere). I can dig but do you think the effort is OK for few percentages (eventually) improvement

Comment: I think so , since the heart of the Kafka is the disk, in our case we intend to add 5-6 disks according to your recommendation so it will be Kafka with JBOD disks, and every   few percentages are important.

Comment: OK, let me dig a bit and tomorrow will edit my answer and ping you

Comment: thank you for your effort and its not so urgent so take your time

Comment: What are the current values of `vm.swappiness, vm.dirty_background_ratio, vm.dirty_ratio, vm.max_map_count`?

Comment: about vm.swappiness , we disable completely the swap by swapoff -a

Comment: vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10

Comment: vm.dirty_ratio = 10

Comment: vm.max_map_count = 1200000

Comment: Check my edited answer. And if possible apply these changes on kind of nonprod system to check if there is any effect w/o interrupting production